# How to clone attributes of a SAX Parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, attributes, sax, saxparser

While using SAX Parser in Java, we have attributes as one of the parameters in the `startElement` method.

Can someone please let me know how to clone this attributes so that it can be stored in a `HashMap<String, Attributes>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[new AttributesImpl(Attributes atts)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html#AttributesImpl-org.xml.sax.Attributes-)

> Copy an existing Attributes object. This constructor is especially
>   useful inside a startElement event.